# Эффект размытия фона за блоком

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, как реализовать такую штуку. Есть меню. С полупрозрачным фоном. Как сделать так, чтобы фон позади меню становился размытым? В интернете нашел только как применить фильтр к блоку в виду чего все содержимое становилось размытым, а все, что позади (на фоне) оставалось обычной резкости.

Answer (score 4):

Для этого можно использовать псевдоэлементы

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;    
    font-family: 'segoe ui', sans-serif;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
}
nav:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc url('http://www.projecthappyhearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/green-nature-dual-monitor-other.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
     filter: blur(10px);
}
nav > ul{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;    
}
nav > ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
}
nav > ul > li:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/bt8a4s3b/)

Comment: А можно ли сделать, чтобы размывалось все позади блока? Вот есть меню и нужно ему придать эффект матового стекла, чтобы все расположенное за ним было размыто. http://cs625221.vk.me/v625221057/3c016/6Npjhd4RCxo.jpg

Comment: так - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6gm4wp4x/?

Comment: не совсем. Тут получается изображение на заднем фоне уже размыто. Мне нужен блок, подвижный, который будет размывать все что на фоне, вне блока. Т.е, наведешь на текст - размоет текст, наведешь на изображение в другом углу - размоет изображение.